# Need to extend grid column and row borders to bottom of Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am adding columns to kendo ui grid dynamically.

When there are many rows in the grid the rows are having borders and displaying it correctly.

But, when there are very few rows in the grid the last row or doesn't seem to show border.

Can the cell borders on a Kendo grid extend to the bottom of the grid area when there are not enough rows in the grid

Comment: any idea how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>() 
           .Name("GirdName")
           .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(100))
           ...


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GirdName>.k-grid-content>table").css("height", 100);
    })
```